# What do default values of pointers in constructors mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, default-value

I try to understand this code (it is taken from [here](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html)):

```
template <class T> class auto_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    explicit auto_ptr(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}
    ~auto_ptr()                 {delete ptr;}
    T& operator*()              {return *ptr;}
    T* operator->()             {return ptr;}
    // ...
};
```

I have problem with understanding this line of the code: `explicit auto_ptr(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}`.

As far as I understand, with this line we try to define a constructor that has one argument of `pointer-to-object-of-T-class` type. Then we have `= 0`. What is that? Is it a default value? But how `0` can be a default value of a pointer (pointer should have addresses as a values, not integer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `= 0` is the default value. For a pointer argument, it is the same as `= NULL`.

To quote [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null):

> **Should I use `NULL` or `0`?**
>
> In C++, the definition of `NULL` is `0`, so there is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use `0`. Another problem with `NULL` is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from `0` and/or not an integer. In pre-standard code, `NULL` was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days.
>
> If you have to name the null pointer, call it `nullptr`; that's what it's called in C++11. Then, `nullptr` will be a keyword.

The formal definition of a null pointer constant is as follows (emphasis mine):

> 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]
>
> 1 **A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero**
>   or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result
>   is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or
>   pointer to function type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion.

`NULL` is defined to be one such constant:

> 18.2 Types [support.types]
>
> 3 The macro `NULL` is an implementation-deﬁned C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10). <sup>192</sup>
>
> <sup>192) Possible deﬁnitions include `0` and `0L`, but not `(void*)0`.</sup>

Comment: I still do not understand how 0 (or NULL) can be used as a value for a pointer. Pointer is an address and address is something different from integer.

Comment: @Roman: Pointers are allowed to have a null value, meaning that they don't point to anything. `0` can be used to represent that value.

Comment: @Roman `0` is a "special" integral value. It can be implicitly converted to a pointer type, representing a null pointer.

Comment: just like 10 can be used as a value for a floating point type because it can be converted, 0 can be used as a value for a pointer type because it can be converted.

Answer (score 3):

```
explicit auto_ptr(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}
```

This is a constructor for `auto_ptr` that takes an `T* p`, if the user does not provide a pointer, `= 0` will be used. The constructor sets the member `ptr` to the argument `: ptr(p)` and does nothing else `{}`. This constructor cannot be used in implicit constructions `explicit`.

Comment: what is "member ptr"? The class does not have such a member. As far as I understand, `:ptr()` means that `auto_ptr(T* p = 0)` constructor should call `ptr(T* p)` constructor of a ptr class.

Comment: @Roman No, David has it right. The member initialiser list specifies how to initialise base classes and members. `auto_ptr` has no base classes, but it does have a member `ptr` (of type `T*`), which is initialised to `p` by this appearance in the mem-initialiser list.

Comment: @Roman: Of course the class has such a member. `T* ptr;` is the very first thing declared in the class.